# Is this the most efficient use of ES6 to find factors without a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, factors

I am trying to find the least verbose way to find the factors for each number in an array without using loops.  I have a snippet of ES6 code that I could use in a .map to avoid a loop I think, but I'm at a loss as to what it is doing in the second line.

I've looked at the .filter and .from methods on MDN, so we're shallow copying an array instance from an iterable, seemingly empty by just calling Array(), but then I'm at a loss in describing it in English  after that, which makes me feel uneasy.

```
let evens = [2,4,6,80,24,36];
```

Here's the ES6 snippet I'm trying to deconstruct/explain in English

```
const factor = number => Array
    .from(Array(number), (_, i) => i)
    .filter(i => number % i === 0)
```

so I dropped it into this .map like so

```
const factors = evens.map((number => {
    return factors(number)
}))

console.log(factors)
```

I get an array of arrays of the factors as shown here

```
[ [ 1 ],
  [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 16, 20, 40 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 18 ] ]
```

So...it works, but what is happening in that second line? I love that it is succinct, but when I try to reverse engineer it into non-ES6 I'm left wondering.

Thank you in advance, advanced ES6 folks.

Comment: "I want to avoid a loop" ... why?

Comment: [Have you read the documentation for `Array.from`?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: As far as efficiency goes....using `for` or `while` loops is probably more efficient....with trade off of  requiring more code

Comment: I should have not used the phrase "without using loops" and instead be more explicit by stating "not explicitly writing for or while loops" since as pointed out below there are loops hiding in the from and filter methods. I very much appreciate the answers. I read MDN "The Array.from() method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like or iterable object", which doesn't mention the map function, but I see that now. I'm still fuzzy on the use of the underscore in the args, but I will continue reading below...

Comment: @BrutalBrutus: the underscore is simply a variable.  It and `$` are allowable characters in variable names.  A number of JS developers follow the convention of using `_` for an argument that must be supplied but is not used.  This comes from several other languages where that is the actual syntax.  So here, the second argument, `i` is used, so we must supply the first one, but we use `_` to signal that we don't care about it.  The convention only goes so far, as we can't use it for multiple unused parameters, but it's a useful shorthand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things to unpack here.

First of all, "without using loops."  Can you explain your reason for that requirement?  Not that I'm unsympathetic, as I usually avoid explicit loops, but you should really be able to explain *why* you want to do this.  There are two fundamentally different ways to process an ordered collection: iterative looping and recursion.  If you're not using recursive code, there's probably a loop hiding somewhere.  It might be buried inside a `map`, `filter`, etc., which is most often an improvement, but that loop is still there.

Second, the layout of this snippet is fairly misleading:

```js
const factor = number => Array
    .from(Array(number), (_, i) => i)
    .filter(i => number % i === 0)
```

Usually when a number of lines start `.methodName(...)` each of these methods operates on the data supplied by the previous line.  But `from` here is just a static method of `Array`; separating them like this is confusing.  Either of these would be better, as would many other layouts:

```js
const factor = number => 
    Array.from(Array(number), (_, i) => i)
    .filter(i => number % i === 0)
```

```js
const factor = number => Array.from(
    Array(number), 
    (_, i) => i
).filter(i => number % i === 0)
```

Third, as comments and another answer have pointed out, `Array.from` accepts an iterable and a mapping function and returns an array, and `Array(number)` will give you an array with no values but which reports its length as `number`, so will serve as an appropriate iterable.  There are a number of equivalent ways one might write this, for instance:

```js
Array.from({length: number}, (_, i) => i)
```

```js
[...Array(number)].map((_, i) => i)
```

Fourth, you mention this:

```js
const factors = evens.map((number => {
    return factor(number)
}))
```

(typo fixed)

While there's nothing exactly wrong with this, you might want to recognize that this can be written much more cleanly as

```js
const factors = evens.map(factor)
```

Finally, that factoring code is missing a major performance tweak.  You test every possible value up to `n`, when you really can find factors in pairs, testing only up to `sqrt(n)`.  That is a major difference.  There is no known efficient factoring technique, which is probably a good thing as modern encryption depends upon this being a difficult problem.  But you most likely don't want to make it much worse than it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

`Array(number)` creates an empty array, with the length `number`. Now as it is completely empty the length is not really useful yet ... if you however call `Array.from` on it, it does iterate over all indices (till `number`) and then calls the  passed callback and builds up a new array with the return values. `(_, i) => i` takes the index of the previous value (which is `undefined` all the time) and returns it as the value. Therefore you get the following results:

```
 number | Array.from
 0            | []
 1            | [0]
 2            | [0, 1]
 5            | [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

As you see, that generates *all numbers* from 0 till `number`. Now you just have to filter out those that evenly divide `number`, which can easily done by checking the result of a modulo operation agains zero:

```
  1 % 2 -> 1
  2 % 2 -> 0
  3 % 2 -> 1
  4 % 2 -> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think a more efficient way would be to use generators.

A bonus is I think the code is easier to understand.

```js
let evens = [2,4,6,80,24,36];

function* factor(n) {
  for (let l = 1; l < n; l += 1) {
    if (n % l === 0) yield l;
  }
}

const factors = evens.map((number => {
  return Array.from(factor(number)).join(", ");
}));

console.log(factors);
```

Comment: Note that the question explicitly asked to avoid loops... although it's not clear why.

Comment: @ScottSauyet  Yeah, I did see that in the subject, but then he uses loops in his examples.

Comment: I'm all for avoiding explicit `for` or `while` loops most of the time; usually code is improved by replacing them with `map`, `filter, `find`, `every`, etc.  But I'm suspicious about making "no loops" a goal, especially as all those techniques have underlying loops to them anyway.

Comment: @ScottSauyet  Not sure the `no loops` goal either..  I'm all for `for` & `while` nowadays, only because they work nicely with `async / await & generators`.  I think the next ES Features is surely making async versions of `map` / `filter` etc..  In the mean time something like -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-iteration seems good if wanting to avoid `for` / `while` etc if doing async stuff.

Comment: I mostly avoid them, but also don't use `async` / `await` all that much either, preferring `Task` or `Future` functions to the `Promises` that underlie it.